# How to add percent labels from raw data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I would like to add percent labels from raw data to a stacked bar plot.

Using this code, I've been able to produce the stacked bar plot. However, I'm struggling to add the labels (in percent) to each category in the bars.

```
ggplot(na.omit(cat.risk.domain), aes(COLE_CATEGORIA, fill=risklevel)) + 
geom_bar(position = 'fill',colour="white")+ scale_y_continuous(labels =scales::percent)
```

[image: how to add percent labels?]

my data looks like this:

```
> dput(frsssubset)
```

structure(list(COLE_CATEGORIA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    domain = c("Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", "Leadership", 
    "Leadership"), risklevel = c("Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", NA, "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", NA, "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo alto", "Sin riesgo", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", NA, "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", NA, "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", NA, "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Sin riesgo", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    NA, "Riesgo medio", "Sin riesgo", NA, "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo medio", 
    "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo medio", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo muy alto", 
    "Riesgo muy alto", "Riesgo bajo", "Riesgo alto", "Riesgo bajo", 
    "Sin riesgo")), .Names = c("COLE_CATEGORIA", "domain", "risklevel"
), row.names = c(NA, 300L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: There isn't enough data in your example to reproduce the plot.

Comment: It's just `geom_text`, but getting the y value right can be finicky

Comment: Thanks - alistaire. Yes, indeed. It's really finicky. And the answers you point to do not address my question.

Comment: try `geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.0f%%",value)),angle = 00 , hjust = 0.5,  vjust = -.5, col = "black", cex = 3, position = position_dodge(.8)) `